# Android detect crash

Tags: java, android

I am getting this crash log for my application:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchModeChanged(AbsListView.java:3543)
android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnTouchModeChanged(ViewTreeObserver.java:732)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchModeLocally(ViewRootImpl.java:3170)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.ensureTouchMode(ViewRootImpl.java:3154)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3347)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4456)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4538)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But i can't see in this lines nothing that point to my code. any idea how i can detect the crash?

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to get an `IllegalStateException` in [`ListView.layoutChildren()`](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#1486) is to make the adapter item count differ from what the listview expected.

This can happen if you changed the data in your listview adapter but forgot to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, or modified the data in a background thread.